# Finding the minimizer of the variational problem $J[y]= \int_{0}^{2} \left( 1-y'^2 \right)^2dx $ with $y(0)=0$ and $y(2)=0$.

Tags: contest-math, calculus-of-variations, functional-calculus

This is a question from a math contest.

Find the minimizer of $J[y]= \int_{0}^{2} \left( 1-y'^2  \right)^2dx$ with the conditions: $y(0)=0$ and $y(2)=0$.

Now as $F$ is $\geq 0$, so to minimize we let $y'^2=1$, $i.e. y'= \pm 1 $ $\implies y= \pm x +c$

but then the initial conditions are not satisfied. So is the only minimizer is $y \equiv  0$?

Also for finding the extremal, using the Euler's condition we have:

$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}- \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} \right] =0 $$
$$ i.e. y''(3y'^2 -1)=0 $$
But I am unable to solve the differential equation.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @Surb Is not it $ y''(3y'^2 -1)=0$?

Comment: @Surb $F=1 + y'^4 + 2y'$ so we have $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=0$ $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} = \frac{d}{dx}(4y'^3 -4y') $ and so $ 3y'^2y'' - y'' =0 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\delta{J}[y]= \delta\int_{0}^{2} \left( 1-y'^2  \right)^2dx=-2\int_{0}^{2} \left( 1-y'^2  \right)y'(\delta{y})'dx=2\int_{0}^{2} \frac{d}{dx}\Bigl(\left( 1-y'^2  \right)y'\Bigr)\delta{y}\,dx$

As $\delta{y}$ is arbitrary $\Rightarrow$
$\frac{d}{dx}\Bigl(\left( 1-y'^2  \right)y'\Bigr)=0$, or $\left( 1-y'^2  \right)y'=C=const$

We got a cubic equation for $y'$ which can be resolved.
All three roots are constants, so we get $y'=C_{1,2,3} = const$ and $y=C_{1,2,3}x+b\,$ ($b\,$ is another constant).

Due to the requirement $y(0)=y(2)=0$ $\,\Rightarrow$ $\,y\equiv0$ at $x\in[0,2]$

Comment: So I understood correctly, then $y \cong 0$ is the only minimizer? Also the question asks about the number of broken points the minimizer have, so in this case the minimizer does not have any broken points. Right?

Comment: "We got a cubic equation for $y'$ which can be resolved..." I don't understand this step, How can we calculate the solution of the differential equation? Is there any standard theorem or can you suggest some reading for some solved examples?

Comment: @Kashif I updated the post - my phrase about an evident solution is not correct. If we consider smooth $y(x)$ after variation we get the equation ${y'}^3 -{y'}^2+C=0$. There are three solutions $y'=c_1;\, y'=c_2; \,y'=c_3$, where $c_1, c_2, c_3$ are constants

Comment: The piece-wise solution $y=x, \,x\in[0,1]$ and $y=2-x, \, x\in[1,2]$ also minimizes the functional ($F[y]=0$)

Comment: Thanks for clearing this. However I have a very naive question, I always have a hard time solving differential equations of type where we have power of derivatives. Can yo provide some reference or clarify how do we go about solving such equations?

Comment: @Kashif I'm afraid there is no a general recipe for solving a differential equation with power of derivatives. In some lucky cases we can get the expression $y'(x) =f(x)$, which can be resolved. As in your problem where we have $y'(x)=const_1\Rightarrow {y'(x)}=const_1{x}+const_2$

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps they allow for continuous and piece-wise differentiable maps?
Then $y(x)=x$, $x\in[0,1]$ and $y(x)=2-x$, $x\in [1,2]$, seems a good candidate. Since you may approximate this arbitrarily well by a $C^1$ function the inf of the functional is zero but is not achieved on $C^1$ functions.

Comment: Yes they allow these functions as well. Actually after this point we are asked about the number of corner points of the minimizer. Now the question seems ambiguous because the marks have been awarded to everyone who attempted the question. So I am curious about the exact reason due to which it was ambiguous. Also you said that the infimum is not achieved in $C^1$ functions, but for $y \cong 0$ the infimum will be achieved, isn't it?

Comment: $J(y\equiv 0)=2$ is not minimizing. There are infinitely many minimizing solutions if you allow piece-wise differentiable functions. Any zig-zag curve consisting of segments of slopes +1 and -1 and joining the two end-points would work. The problem is a bit awkward for a contest.

Comment: Yes you are right! the marks were awarded to everyone who attempted the question, this was an awkward question indeed. Thanks!